# Lowercase of nouns not correct in German

Tags: java, locale, lowercase

My application uses resouce bundles for different languages (I18N).

```
string.toLowerCase()
```

Lowercase is used all over the application to combine sentences.

**problem**: lowerCase is not correct for *German* nouns.

Resource bundle:

- English: resource_day = **D**ay
- German: resource_day = **T**ag

Sentence:

- in English: This is the first **d**ay.
- in German: Dies ist der erste **T**ag.

Like you can see: The German language uses *capital* letters for the nouns.

Code:

```
sentence = resource_start + number + resource_day.toLowerCase();
```

What is the best way to differentiate the english and german language?

Comment: how about keeping single words lowercase in resource bundles (but uppercase in case of german nouns) and make them uppercase when needed (i.e. the opposite of your current approach)?

Comment: I was hoping not to do this, but this might be the only solution. My resource bundle is quit long, and this string concatenation is used every where. This would turn out in a lot of work with risk of forgetting some keywords. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Why would you even bother combining sentences? Just write them all out and you'll have both correct German capitalization **and** less useless logic for combining text.

Comment: This sentence is just an example. Other examples are keywords that live after dropdown boxes or labels before and after input fields. Not an ideal world, but this is the current state of the project. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do that would be to store full sentences in your resources and use placeholders for the variable parts:

**EN**

```
resource_day = This is the {0} day.
day_first = first
```

**DE**

```
resource_day = Dies ist der {0} Tag.
day_first = erste
```

And use it as

```
String day_number = "day_first";
MessageFormat.format(RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString("resource_day"), 
   RESOURCE_BUNDLE.getString(day_number);
```